# настройка php.ini после установки php_curl

Tags: php, curl

Сервер на debian7 установил curl:

```
apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl
```

после дописал в php.ini:

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

Вот что написало в логах yii:

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/php_curl.dll' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/php_curl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

заменил на extension=/usr/lib/php5/20100525/curl.so, в логах:

```
Module 'curl' already loaded
```

После того как удалил свои правки - все заработало, но в php.ini CURL нигде не прописывается, он еще где-то подключается?

Comment: Посмотрите phpinfo(), есть ли в нем CURL

Comment: вы скорее всего `cli` поправили

Comment: @therainycat , да curl есть, т.к функционал сайта его юзает.

Comment: @Naumov - каким образом я это сделал? может ispmanager что-то правит после перезапуска сервера с панели?

Comment: вы php.ini не тот поправили короче

Answer (score 2):

```
root@ec3168356aaa:/etc/php5#pwd
/etc/php5
root@ec3168356aaa:/etc/php5# ack-grep curl
fpm/php.ini
1925:[curl]
1928:;curl.cainfo =

cli/php.ini
1923:[curl]
1926:;curl.cainfo =

apache2/php.ini
1928:[curl]
1931:;curl.cainfo =

mods-available/curl.ini
3:extension=curl.so
```

в mods-available он подключается, причем подключается и для CLI и для php-fpm

и руками дописывать его в php.ini не нужно, поскольку вы поставили пакет `php5-curl`, который все за вас сделал.

если бы вы компилировали какое-нибудь расширение руками, вам пришлось бы добавить что-нибудь вроде

`extension=/usr/lib/php5/20131226/runkit.so` в php.ini